# Redis consumes max memory on large DEL & HMSET function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, memory, redis

**Issue: After expected clear and rebuild of specific redis keys, worker dynos doesn't allocate memory (until restart of dyno).**

I am experience an issue where my Heroku worker-dynos are hitting **95%-100%** max memory usage during a delete and rebuild on about **4000** keys. I have a scheduled rebuild that starts every day at 4:00am. Based on logs I assume the DEL of the keys + the rebuild of keys take about **~1490** seconds.

```
Jun 29 04:01:41 app app/worker.2: 4 TID-...io8w RedisWorker JID-...cd2a7 INFO: start 
Jun 29 04:06:28 app app/worker.1: 4 TID-...mtks RedisWorker JID-...bf170 INFO: start 
Jun 29 04:26:32 app app/worker.1: 4 TID-...mtks RedisWorker JID-...bf170 INFO: done: 1203.71 sec 
Jun 29 04:26:33 app app/worker.2: 4 TID-...io8w RedisWorker JID-...cd2a7 INFO: done: 1490.938 sec
```

The memory will hover max usage until the dyno restarts (which is scheduled) or we deploy. Example image: [Heroku Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaxC9.png)

This is a high level what gets triggered at 4am:

```
  def full_clear
    RedisWorker.delete_keys("key1*")
    RedisWorker.delete_keys("key2*")
    RedisWorker.delete_keys("key3*")
    self.build
    return true
  end

  def build
    ... rebuilds keys based on models ... 
    return true
  end

  def self.delete_keys(regex)
    $redis.scan_each(match: regex) do |key|
      $redis.del(key)
    end
  end
```

What I have researched so far or my thoughts:

- After redis DEL is being invoked the memory doesn't allocate?
- Could there be a better implementation of finding all keys that match and doing a batch delete?
- I am using defaults for puma; would configuring puma+sidekiq to better match our resources help be the best starting action? [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server). After a restart the memory is only about 30%-40% until the next full-rebuild (even during high usage of hmsets).
- I noticed that my ObjectSpace counts is comparably a lot lower after the dyno gets restart/rest of day until next scheduled full_rebuild.

**Any thoughts how I can go about trying to figure out whats causing the dynos to hang memory? Seems isloated to side / the worker dynos being used do rebuild Redis.**

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I installed New Relic to see if there was a potential memory bloat. One of our most used function calls was doing a N+1 query. Fixed the N+1 query and watched our 60k call in New Relic drop to ~5K.

GC also wasn't collecting because it wasn't hitting our threshold. Later on there might be potential GC optimization -- but for now we our immediate issue has been resolved.

I also reached out to Heroku for their thoughts and this is what was discussed:

> Memory usage on the Dyno will be managed by the Ruby VM, and is likely that you're keep ing too much information in memory during the key rebuild. You should look into freeing memory used to generate the key-values after the data has been added redis.

Spending time fixing your N+1 queries will definitely help!